# Macro to copy to next blank row on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this macro to copy from one sheet to another based on text in one cell, but it overwrites the data every time I run the macro. Is there any way to change the macro so that any data it pastes is in the next blank row?

Thanks :)

```
Sub CopyYes()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Data")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cheque Data")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "Cheque" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Data")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gift Card Data")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "Gift Card" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Data")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Promo Code Data")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "Promo Code" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c

Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2:F200").ClearContents
Sheets("Main Data").Range("J2:Q200").ClearContents
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Before each `j=1` add

```
lastrow = Target.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And change `j = 1` to `j = lastrow`